# Laravel 9 Sail port forward error for mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laravel-9, mysql-8.0, laravel-sail

I have port forwarded applications mysql port to `3307` because I need my host mysql to keep running at `3306`, but it gives below error.

Also I am able to get welcome page after running `sail up`

I am using laravel 9 latest version

## Error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

PHP 8.1.9
9.26.1

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

SELECT count(*) AS aggregate FROM `users` WHERE `email` = test@test.com
```

## .env

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1
APP_PORT=81

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

## docker-composer.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-81}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5174}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '{DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '{DB_HOST}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '{DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '{DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '{DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

## Update 1

My terminal ouput is as follows

```
sm_v2-laravel.test-1   "start-container"   laravel.test        exited (0)          
Shutting down old Sail processes...
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠙ Network sm_v2_sail  Creating                                                                                      0.2s
[+] Running 3/3d orphan containers ([sm_v2-service-1]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your co ⠿ Network sm_v2_sail              Created                                                                           0.2s
 ⠿ Container sm_v2-mysql-1         Created                                                                           1.5s
 ⠿ Container sm_v2-laravel.test-1  Created                                                                           0.5s
Attaching to sm_v2-laravel.test-1, sm_v2-mysql-1
sm_v2-mysql-1         | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.30-1.2.9-server
sm_v2-mysql-1         | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.30-1.2.9-server
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.087084Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.092964Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.148193Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.303213Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.755173Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.755609Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.755681Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
sm_v2-mysql-1         | 2022-08-30T15:19:04.757223Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
sm_v2-mysql-1 exited with code 1
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-30 15:19:07,746 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-30 15:19:07,751 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-30 15:19:08,756 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 16
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-30 15:19:09,759 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |    INFO  Server running on [http://0.0.0.0:80].  
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  | 
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:21 ................................................... ~ 1s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:23 /favicon.ico ...................................... ~ 0s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:23 ................................................... ~ 1s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:24 /build/assets/app.ac81e540.css .................... ~ 0s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:24 /build/assets/app.ab93cf8a.js ..................... ~ 0s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:24 /favicon.ico ...................................... ~ 0s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:27 ................................................... ~ 0s
sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 15:19:29 /favicon.ico ...................................... ~ 0s
    sm_v2-laravel.test-1  |   2022-08-30 16:07:14 ................................................... ~ 0s
```

## Update 2

I get different error now

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.128.3' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: your database fails to start so there is nothing running there: `sm_v2-mysql-1 exited with code 1`. You need to stop docker compose and remove all volumes then try again. Make sure your DB is up and running when you try to connect to it

Comment: @Mihai I have got a new error after this, please see `Update 2` section of the question.

Comment: that is strictly related to your app. check if the app uses the right password for root. also in Mysql you need to allow root access from `%` so everywhere not only localhost. best would be to use other user than root

Comment: @Mihai Mysql means the mysql running on the host of my computer or I need to go to the containers mysql, I am a bit mew to this

Comment: the one that you are trying to connect to.... you know that from the connection url in your app. I would say the one in the container based on your post here

Comment: @Mihai

I added like these

`
CREATE USER 'root@192.168.160.3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
grant all on *.* to 'root@192.168.160.3'@'%';
`
It shows me

`
+--------------------+
| user               |
+--------------------+
| root               |
| root@192.168.160.3 |
| sm_v2              |
| root               |
| root               |
| root               |
| root               |
| debian-sys-maint   |
| mysql.infoschema   |
| mysql.session      |
| mysql.sys          |
+--------------------+
`
am I doing it correct because it still gives the same error

Comment: this  'root@192.168.160.3'@'%'  needs to be  'root'@'%'

Comment: @Mihai I added it and it looks like below, but it does not work, it still gives me the same error

`
+------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| user             | host      | account_locked | password_expired |
+------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| root             | %         | N              | N                |
`

Comment: @Mihai any idea reagarding above issue ?

Comment: you still get the same "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.128.3'"? How do you run the queries to see the user accounts?

Comment: queries does not run, when I try to sign up and I get the error message

Comment: You are posting some query results in these comments. How do you run those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it after mental frustation of more than a week. But it is very strange that no one was able to provide any answer in any forums, yes I tried all the famous forums possible.

I made sure that two users are added on my host(main computer) machine not the docker mysql, and I granted them full grant using mysql cli, there were 2 entries like these along with other entries

```
root | %
root | localhost
```

I ran following commands one after another. I don't know which commands exactly solved the problem as I am a beginner in docker and sail but here are my steps that I tried after which it started working.

I was getting `Docker is not running.` , so I tried following to make docker running.

```bash
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable docker.socket
```

After that I tried `sail up` but it did not work, so ran following

```bash
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl disable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sail up
```

After that I rebooted my computer (I am on Ubuntu 22.04)

```bash
reboot
```

Removed some unnecessary files, also I got some failed error in docker service which I solved by running line 2&3 of the code below

```bash
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
sudo systemctl reset-failed docker.service
sudo systemctl start docker.service
systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

```bash
sail down
sail build --no-cache
sail up
```

```bash
php artisan config:clear
```

After that I migrated database and it worked

```
sail artisan migrate
```

After that

```bash
sudo systemctl enable docker
sail up
sail build
sail ps
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

Removed `daemon.json`

```
sudo rm daemon.json
```

Removed old volumes

### I think this was helpful

```
sail down --rmi all -v
sail up / (you can use sail up --no-cache)
```

Now mysql works on host computer port `3306` as well as other ports used for docker `3307`,`3308` simultaneously

I Appreciate @Mihai  effort becoz only @Mihai responded in the comments

### Update 2

I had to add `platform: 'linux/x86_64'`  in `docker-compose.yml` file

```
mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        platform: 'linux/x86_64'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
```